# Any babel plugin to remove unnecessary assignment?

Tags: javascript, babeljs, terser

I am trying to optimize my bundle and I want to transform code from this:

```js
  const tmp = '1'
  obj['a'] = tmp
  str += tmp
```

to this:

```js
  let str = ''
  const obj = {}
  str += obj['a'] = '1'
```

Is there any babel plugin for this kind of transformation? Or would it be handled by minifier like Terser?

Comment: Does this really pose a problem? I don't expect such code snippets to have any noticeable impact on bundle size. Not unless there is excessively many of them already. And if you're concerned with speed, I'd just drop it and try to focus on finding actual bottlenecks.

Comment: Yes this issue is very very minor. But I have too much time to slack at work LOL. That's why I am wondering how can I make my opensource package even better and faster.